# How do I consolidate multiple lists (nested list) into a single list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

for example, I get

```
[[], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1], [3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
[[1, 2, 3], [5]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], []]
```

And I want to convert first list into [2,3,4,5], next [1,3,4,5], et cetera.
I try to mutiply them all together but of course a list cannot mutiply a interger.

Comment: `[] + [2, 3, 4, 5]` will be `[2, 3, 4, 5]`; `[1] + [3, 4, 5]` will be `[1, 3, 4, 5]` etc.

Comment: You *can* multiply a list and an integer: e.g., `a * 3 == 3 * a == a + a + a`. Multiplication simply isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[1, 2], [4, 5]]))
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```